# Transpose rows to column and join table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, pivot

Hi I have two tables Attribute, Instance

**Attribute Table**

```
id  |    key_info   |   value_info
2   |     amount    |    1009
2   |   currency    |     USD
2   |     Level     |    Level 5
3   |    amount     |     2017 
3   |   currency    |     CAD
```

**Instance Table**

```
id   |  status
2    | Pending 
3    | Approved
```

I want to join two tables like this-

**New table**

```
id | amount |  currrency | level   | status
2  |  1001  |     USD    | Level 5 | Pending
3  |   2017 |     CAD    |         | Approved
```

All the fields in the Attribute and Instance are optional except id.

Comment: Which RBDMS is this for?  MySql?  Sql Server?  Each platform implements pivot functionality differently.

Comment: It is for SQL server 2008. The above query worked.Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
select
  a.id,
  max(case when a.key_info = 'amount' then a.value_info end) as amount,
  max(case when a.key_info = 'currency' then a.value_info end) as currency,
  max(case when a.key_info = 'level' then a.value_info end) as level,
  i.status
from
  attribute a
  join instance i on a.id = i.id
group by
  a.id,
  i.status
```

### [Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2ecd66/6)

Answer (score 9):

Starting in SQL Server 2005, the [`PIVOT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) function can perform this conversion from rows to columns:

```
select id, 
  amount, 
  currency, 
  level,
  status
from 
(
  select i.id, i.status,
    a.key_info,
    a.value_info
  from instance i
  inner join attribute a
    on i.id = a.id
) src
pivot
(
  max(value_info)
  for key_info in (amount, currency, level)
) piv
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6e689/2).

If you have an unknown number of `key_values` then you can use dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(key_info) 
                    from Attribute
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT id, ' + @cols + ', status from 
             (
                select i.id, i.status,
                  a.key_info,
                  a.value_info
                from instance i
                inner join attribute a
                  on i.id = a.id
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(value_info)
                for key_info in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6e689/4). Both give the result:

```
| ID | AMOUNT | CURRENCY |   LEVEL |   STATUS |
-----------------------------------------------
|  2 |   1009 |      USD | Level 5 |  Pending |
|  3 |   2017 |      CAD |  (null) | Approved |
```